# How To Fix an Azure-Only Active Directory Environment

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, wsus, entra-id

I just recently started my first job in IT and have been tasked with deploying 60 new laptops right off the bat. I have set up WSUS on our server as the first order of business, but there is a problem I am facing with our Active Directory. The person in charge before me decided to remove the local AD and attempt to replace it with an Azure AD. I have come to understand that Azure AD is not a replacement for a local AD and has given me quite the challenge. Using Azure AD Connect, I attempted to sync the directories. This worked, however since our Azure AD is our "main" AD, I cannot seem to pull users and groups from it to assign GPOs for updating via WSUS. Is there something I am missing? Or can a Local AD really not be used as a "secondary" AD only for WSUS/GPO assigning? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: don't forget you'll also need Azure AD DS (Domain Services).

Answer (score 2):

He did what with the old DC ? On my side I would restore an old DC backup, or restart the VM if lucky that he didnt erased that VM in example.

As Azure AD only keep password hash/user in example, it's not a full AD sync.It's a identity and access management service.

Per the doc;

> **Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) is Microsoft’s cloud-based identity
>   and access management service**. Azure AD helps your employees sign in
>   and access resources in:
>
> External resources, such as Microsoft Office 365, the Azure portal,
>   and thousands of other SaaS applications.
>
> Internal resources, such as apps on your corporate network and
>   intranet, along with any cloud apps developed by your own
>   organization.
>
> You can use the various Microsoft Cloud for Enterprise Architects
>   Series posters to better understand the core identity services in
>   Azure, Azure AD, and Office 365.
>
> Who uses Azure AD? Azure AD is intended for:
>
> IT admins. As an IT admin, you can use Azure AD to control access to
>   your apps and your app resources, based on your business requirements.
>   For example, you can use Azure AD to require multi-factor
>   authentication when accessing important organizational resources.
>   Additionally, you can use Azure AD to automate user provisioning
>   between your existing Windows Server AD and your cloud apps, including
>   Office 365. Finally, Azure AD gives you powerful tools to
>   automatically help protect user identities and credentials and to meet
>   your access governance requirements. To get started, sign up for a
>   free 30-day Azure Active Directory Premium trial.

Your old admin must probably wanted to migrate the AD to the cloud, then the way a migration to the cloud must be made is to lease a VM on the cloud and build your AD from there or to use [Azure ADDS Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview) | https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview

Comment: The old DC is gone as far as I am aware of. And is i possible to migrate the AAD to an AD using a physical machine rather than a VM? I was under the impression that the Azure AD Connect program is capable of syncing the AAD and the AD, but I don't believe that the local AD can be set as a "backup" or "secondary" (kind of like refreshing the local AD with the AAD, rather than the current way it works). If I was mislead, then a VM will work better in conjunction with Azure rather than a local machine?

Comment: @NikolaiOnABear VM or not, I mean more that Azure AD is not a full Active Directory like the ADDS's role you configure in a Windows Server. You can see there for the feature that was asked, but not yet there; https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/6455327-sync-azure-active-directory-down-to-on-premises-ad

Comment: Ah thank you, I was looking at that feature request prior to asking. So with all of our user information being only in the AAD, how would you recommend setting up a Local AD in conjunction with AAD in order to assign Group Policies? Or is this something that is just not possible without complete migration to a primary Local AD using the AAD as a backup?

Comment: @NikolaiOnABear Make sure if you use AAD or Azure ADDS service, as if only AAD you will be left with the only option to restore, or to build a new AD, and build a new connector to AAD after sadly (not good new). Make me wonder if the last technician did that on purpose

Comment: So the best solution would be to just pay for one of the cheaper VMs on Azure to push GPs to domain users? But still host the WSUS/MDT on a local machine and just point the clients to the server with the policies?

Comment: @NikolaiOnABear No, I mean you are stuck, as Azure AAD can't sync back. I tell some solution that would had been the correct solution to ahve a azure in the cloud, but no in your case, unless someone corrcet me, you are out of luck

Comment: Yes, this is an example of an unfortunate thing. If you have a backup of that AD forest, that would be helpful. But any data you seek that isn't simply users/passwords/roles is simply not there in Azure.

Comment: I don't believe there was any data other than users/passwords/roles in our AD before I got here. The only thing we use AAD for users logging into other devices and logging in without being on our network (everyone has a laptop and is in and out of the office a lot). If I could just manage the users with GPO then I can do the rest with WSUS and MDT. Another suggestion that was made to me was Intune in collaboration with AAD. I am not sure if Intune can handle WSUS or MDT but I heard there were permission-level caveats with it causing it to not follow the OU>Domain>Site>Local syntax that GPs do

Comment: @NikolaiOnABear Your AAD on azure will never update from a local AD, you have none now. If your AD is simple, then recreate it, turning back a wrong decision is easier at first step, not after a lot of errors to try to fix error #1.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone! I have a start in the right direction now, I really appreciate it